# What sort of molecules or polymers are used in OLED displays?

Tags: organic-chemistry, structural-formula, semiconductors

[OLED displays](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED) have been emerging as competitors for LCD displays for some time and are now common in mobile phones (see comparison of a Google Nexus 1 and an iPhone [here](http://www.displaymate.com/Nexus_One_ShootOut.htm))

The displays use small molecules or polymers that emit light when a current is passed through them (like a semiconductor LED). But what is the structure of the emitters?

Comment: The Wikipedia article you link to lists a number of [popular emitters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OLED#Material_technologies), give their structures, and link to more comprehensive articles about them. I'm not sure what else you want. Is their something deficient about the Wikipedia article(s)? Help us help you.

Comment: @BenNorris The wikipedia article doesn't provide much detail. I was hoping that someone who knows the current state of the industry would provide some more recent examples. There are several companies with OLED tech and I don't think they all use the same chemicals. I think a good review would make a good answer for this site.

Answer (score 7):

A typical organic light emitting diode (OLED) structure consisting of a glass substrate, a indium titanium oxide (ITO) anode, and an organic bilayer diffused into a metallic cathode, is given below:

[image]

The organic bilayer consists of:

- a **hole transport layer (HTL)**, typically of N, N'-diphenyl-N, N'-bis(3-methylphenyl) 1, 1'-biphenyl-4, 4' diamine (TPD) or N,N′-di(naphthalene-1-yl)-N,N′- diphenylbenzidine (NPB)
- an **emitting/electron transport layer (EML/ETL)**, typically of tris(8- hydroxyquinoline) aluminum (Alq3)

Source: http://espace.library.uq.edu.au/eserv.php?pid=UQ:8598&dsID=SMS.pdf